# Prob. 7 (b), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Example of a function such that $\lim_{c \to 0+} \int_c^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ exists but . . .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Here is Prob. 7, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $(0, 1]$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[c, 1]$ for every $c > 0$. Define 
>   $$ \int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_c^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x $$ 
>   if this limit exists (and is finite).
>
> (a) If $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0, 1]$, show that this definition of the integral agrees with the old one.
>
> (b) Construct a function $f$ such that the above limit exists, although it fails to exist with $\lvert f \rvert$ in place of $f$.

Here is the link to my post on Prob. 7 (a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin:

[Prob. 7 (a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $f$ is integrable on $[c, 1]$ for every $c>0$, then $\int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = $ . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375688/prob-7-a-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-f-is-integrable-on-c-1-for-every)

And, here is the link to a post of mine here on Math SE where I've copied the definition of the Riemann and Riemann-Stieltjes integral that Rudin uses (i.e. Definitions 6.1 and 6.2 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition):

[Theorem 6.10 in Baby Rudin: If $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$ with only finitely many points of discontinuity at which $\alpha$ is continuous, then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319741/theorem-6-10-in-baby-rudin-if-f-is-bounded-on-a-b-with-only-finitely-man)

Here I'll be attempting only Part (b).

My Attempt:

> Let $f$ be the function defined on $(0, 1]$ by 
>   $$ f(x) = (-1)^n n  \  \mbox{ if } \  n \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ and } \ \frac{1}{n+1} < x \leq \frac{1}{n}. \tag{0} $$
>
> If $0 < c \leq 1$, then there is a smallest natural number $N$ such that 
>   $$ N \leq \frac{1}{c} < N+1. \tag{1} $$ 
>   Then 
>   $$ \frac{1}{N+1} < c \leq \frac{1}{N}. \tag{1'} $$
>
> So 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \int_c^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x &= \int_c^{1/N} f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x + \sum_{k=0}^{N-2} \int_{ 1/(N-k) }^{ 1/(N-k-1) } f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> &= \int_c^{1/N} (-1)^N N  \ \mathrm{d} x + \sum_{k=0}^{N-2} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0+ } \int_{1/(N-k)+\varepsilon}^{ 1/(N-k-1) } (-1)^{N-k-1} (N-k-1) \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> & \qquad \mbox{ [ using (0) above and Prob. 3.7(a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin ] } \\
> &= (-1)^N N \left( \frac{1}{N} - c \right) \\
> & \qquad + \sum_{k=0}^{N-2} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0+ } (-1)^{N-k-1} (N-k-1) \left( \frac{1}{N-k-1} - \frac{1}{N-k} - \varepsilon \right) \\
> & \qquad \mbox{ [ using Theorem 6.21 in Baby Rudin ] } \\
> &= (-1)^N N \left( \frac{1}{N} - c \right) \\
> & \qquad + \sum_{k=0}^{N-2}  (-1)^{N-k-1} (N-k-1) \left( \frac{1}{N-k-1} - \frac{1}{N-k} \right) \\
> &= (-1)^N (1- cN) + \sum_{k=0}^{N-2} (-1)^{N-k-1} \frac{1}{N-k} \\
> &= (-1)^N (1-cN) + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} (-1)^{N-k} \frac{1}{N-k + 1 } \\
> &= (-1)^N (1-cN) + \sum_{r=1}^{N-1} (-1)^r \frac{1}{r+1}. \tag{2} 
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Now as $c \to 0+$, then from (1) we can conclude that $N+1 \to \infty$ (through natural numbers), which happens if and only if $N \to \infty$, and so 
>   $$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{N-1} (-1)^r \frac{1}{r+1} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r}{r+1}, \tag{3} $$
>   which is a real number, by virtue of Theorem 3.43 in Baby Rudin.
>
> And, 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \left\lvert (-1)^N (1-cN) \right\rvert &= \left\lvert 1-cN  \right\rvert \\ 
> &= 1 - cN \\
> &< 1 - \frac{N}{N+1} \\
> &= \frac{1}{N+1}. \tag{4}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Now as 
>   $$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N+1} = 0, $$
>   so from (4) we can conclude that 
>   $$\lim_{c \to 0+}  (-1)^N (1-cN) = 0. \tag{5} $$
>
> Thus from (2), (3), and (5) we can conclude that 
>   $$ \lim_{c \to 0+} \int_c^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x$$
>   does exist in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> On the other hand, from (2) we can also obtain 
>   $$ \int_c^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert \ \mathrm{d} x = ( 1- cN) + \sum_{r=1}^{N-1}  \frac{1}{r+1}, $$ 
>   and so 
>   $$ \lim_{c \to 0+}  \int_c^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert \ \mathrm{d} x = 0 + \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r+1} = + \infty. $$
>
> Thus the function $f$ defined in (0) above provides a required example.

Is this the kind of example that Rudin requires?

Is what I've done so far correct? If so, then what next? If not, then where have I erred and how to rectify my mistake?

Comment: I didn't scrutinize your answer, but if I have time I'll do so later. However, I did provide you an easy example for your question.

Comment: You example for (b) is  valid, but I think it can be verified a lot more briefly.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you're right, but I've a tendency of writing up my posts by including a lot of detail and thereby trying to ensure that someone who is taking their very first course in this field can also understand my answers / proofs without having to look deep. It's based on my personal experiences as a student of math with little tutorial support.

Answer (score 2):

One classical example of conditional convergence for improper integrals is $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ - this converges, but $\int_1^\infty\left|\frac{\sin}{x}\right|dx$ diverges. With the substitution of $u = \frac{1}{x}$ we can obtain that $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{u})}{u}du$ converges and $\int_0^1 |\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{u})}{u}|du$ diverges.

In general, casually modifying simple examples like this is usually the easiest route to an answer.